# message passing in python

Tags: python, logging, object

I read about this metaphor that objects use message passing while passing a message to another object. is it possible to capture/log such messages! This is for my learning purposes, but thought it would be necessary a handly tool for a provenance system!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

In essence it allows you to capture object events such method invocation and apply some logic to them. In your case it'd be just print out some traces.

Have a look at [A Lightweight Approach to Aspect-Oriented Programming in Python](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~ask/aspects/index.shtml), it should do what you need.